# Regex: Difference between (?=.*gh) and (?=\w*gh)

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I am new to Regex and I am can't seem to solve this:

When trying to match words that contain "gh" using positive lookahead:

**(?=\w*gh)** Works perfectly but **(?=.*gh)** matches every word.

Can someone help me with this please. Why does the Regex with the wildcard fail to match only words that contains a 'gh'?

Eg:

`\b(?=\w*gh)[a-z]+\b` matches only words with 'gh' `right`, cat, `tight`, dog

but

`\b(?=.*gh)[a-z]+\b` matches everything: `right`, `cat`, `tight`, `dog`

Comment: Just because `. ` means any character... so it will takes anything up to gh.

Comment: @tensibai thanks for your reply! rly appreciate it (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` in regex matches any character except line terminators. This includes whitespace.

So `(?=.*gh)` will match everything in the text up to the characters 'gh'

e.g.

`Isle of Wi`ght

If you have two or more words containing 'gh', it'll match the entire text up to the last one, since the preceding 'gh's match `.`

e.g.

`Isle of Wight fli`ghts

`\w` matches only word characters. i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`so it won't match whitespace and therefore won't capture all the words before the one containing 'gh'

e.g.

Isle of `Wi`ght

**Update**

Your edited regex will take the text captured by the lookahead (see above) and then match all words in it. 'Dog' is never captured in your example.

Try using https://regex101.com/

Given: right, cat, tight, dog

`\b(?=.*gh)[a-z]+\b` matches `right`, `cat`, `tight`, dog

`\b(?=\w*gh)[a-z]+\b` matches `right`, cat, `tight`, dog

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply JamesT,
`\b(?=\w*gh)[a-z]+\b'`matches only words with "gh" in them  
eg: `light`, ball, `tight`, cat.  

However `\b(?=.*gh)[a-z]+\b'` matches all 4 words  
eg: `light`, `ball`, `tight`, `cat`  --> So why does this version fail, even though i specified 'gh' after the wildcard `.`

Comment: Same reason. the `.*` in the lookahead captures everything up to the last gh, and your `\b`s capture all words in that lookahead. Cat isn't captured in your example

Comment: Ok got it! Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it :). Happy Holidays!